# Dirichlet theorem on primes premise

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> Dirichlet theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions: Suppose a and
>   b are positive coprime integers, then $\exists$ infinitely many primes
>   $p$ such that $p\equiv a\pmod b$.

Why is it necessary for a and b to be coprime?

My approach is to suppose $gcd(a,b)=d$ with $d>1$ such that $a'=\frac{a}{d}$ and $b'=\frac{b}{d}$.

If $p\equiv a\pmod b$ this implies $p-a=bq$ for $q\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p=bq+a$

If we divide both sides by $d$, we get $\frac{p}{d}=b'q+a'$

$p$ is prime so $d$ does not divide $p$ and $b'q+a'$ is an integer which means $\frac{p}{d}\ne b'q+a'$

So if $a$ and $b$ are not coprime, then $p$ cannot be congruent $a$ modulo $b$.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: $2$ is not coprime with $6$. How many primes $\equiv 2 \bmod 6$ ? And the premise of Dirichlet theorem is to look at Dirichlet characters $\bmod p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. Note that $2$ is prime and $2$ and $2$ are *not* coprime, but $2\equiv2\pmod 2$.

What happens when $a$ and $b$ are *not* coprime is that there is at most one prime number $p$ such that $p\equiv a\pmod b$.

Comment: Indeed, the number of such primes is at most $1$.

Comment: @Wojowu Right. I will edit my answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, thank you for your counterexample. How should I go about showing that the condition "$a$ and $b$ are coprime" is necessary?

Comment: @Sadem Suppose that they are not. If $p\equiv a\pmod b$, then $p$ is a multiple of $\gcd(a,b)>1$. But, given a natural number greater than $1$, there is, at most, one prime number among its multiples.